# How can I tell what the hundreds/thousands digits are in a players level?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Since Heroes of the Storm 2.0 dropped, player levels are now determined by their character levels.

However, it only uses a two digit number for display with the colors and borders changing instead of having a 3+ digit number.

What do the various number colors and borders mean level-wise?

Comment: The hundreds digit was added some time ago, so this is more or less a dead question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based off [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/heroesofthestorm/comments/67jvni/hero_level_portraitcolor_marking_breakdown/), it is the following:

```
Level |   Color 
---------------
100   |   Green
200   |   Teal
300   |   Purple
400   |   Red
500   |   Yellow
```

> Repeating over and over. You get additional gems on your portrait and
>   your portrait shape improves each cycle.

To give you an idea, this is what the borders look like:

[image: Borders]

<sub><sub>[(Source)](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/heroes20/progression/)</sub></sub>

According to the image source:

> Your portrait badge art will become more intricate for every 25 levels you earn. Upon reaching level 100, your visible level will reset to 1 and you’ll don a badge that’s even more epic so that you can show off your dedication anywhere your portrait is visible.

I think the [Wiki's description](http://heroesofthestorm.wikia.com/wiki/Player_Level) is better however:

> - Player progression badge art will receive more decoration every 25 player levels.
> - Every 100 player levels, the level displayed in the progression badge will reset, and the badge will upgrade with even more ornate
>     artwork.
> - The Basic Portrait Border will update every 100 levels with new art that matches the player’s progression badge.

Comment: Every portrait box I've seen is just a plain box (though different colors), none of those decorative circles on them.

Comment: @sirjonsnow I think what they're saying on reddit is the dots only appear after 600 (when you allegedly reset to green).  The announcement description seems out of date.

Comment: Yep, I can see a [gold border with a single dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En5fX.png) on the loading screen for someone that has player level 1057.

Comment: And here's proof [the colors reset at 600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvC4w.png).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I don't like it though - I shouldn't have to look up/memorize a matrix to know someone's level.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of posting [Timmy Jim's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/308332/559) was correct. Based on feedback about how confusing determining a player's level was Blizzard made a [UI change on May 16, 2017](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/20783378/heroes-of-the-storm-patch-notes-may-16-2017-5-16-2017#User_Interface):

> Player levels displayed in portraits have received visual updates, and should be easier to distinguish while using the progression portrait border.

Comment: More specifically, the two changes were adding a black line around the number (so you could read it), and showing the total player level instead of just the last two digits.

Comment: @Troyen feel free to edit that into the answer.